# Return a varchar(max) from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to return a `varchar(max)` from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008.

So I tried:

```
alter proc SpSignup(
    @username varchar(max),
    @email varchar(max),
    @password varchar(max),
    @warning varchar(max) output)
as
   if exists(select email from [login] where email=@email)
      return 'email already exists';

   insert into [login](username, email, password) 
   values(@username, @email, @password)
```

I want to return a `varchar` value (`'email already exists'`) if the email exists in the table, and don't want to give any `@warning` as parameter.

But it shows that `@warning para is not supplying` after exec this proc

> *Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure SpSignup, Line 0*
>   *Procedure or function 'SpSignup' expects parameter '@warning', which was not supplied.*

and also it doesn't shows the output (`'email already exists'`)

Comment: **HOW** do you execute this procedure? Show us that code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to supply parameter `@username` into your procedure

```
declare @warning varchar(max)

exec SpSignup
    @username = 'Bill', 
    @email = 'Bill@gmail.com',
    @password = '12345',
    @warning = @warning output

select @warning
```

**UPDATE**: It's not possible to return `varchar` variable from procedure, you can pass it as `output` parameter or you can just code `select 'email already exists'` or `print 'email already exists'`

```
alter proc SpSignup
(
    @username varchar(max),
    @email varchar(max),
    @password varchar(max)
)
as
begin
    if exists(select email from [login] where email=@email)
    begin
        select 'email already exists'
        print 'email already exists'
        return
    end

    insert into [login](username, email, password) values(@username, @email, @password)
end
```

Comment: i think you'd not getting the problem,,,explain again that want to return a varchar value('email already exists') , if email exists in table,  and dont want to give any '@warning' as parameter.